# Supply user specific dependencies to MVC controller with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have some controllers that require a web service connection (an instance of MS Dynamics CRM `CrmService`) and I would like the controllers to receive this through their constructors. The CRM service has to be set up with a token that is based on who the currently logged in user is (when the user logs in the application authenticates against the CRM and can store the returned token in Session).

I'm not sure how best to supply this instance using Dependency Injection and Ninject. It seems a bit rubbish for the Ninject `ToMethod()` Func<> to access FormsAuth/Session for the current request (to obtain the token if authenticated) to create the appropriate instance. I'm also not sure what should happen if the user is not authenticated - I don't need these users be able to access the controller but the controller will be instantiated before any filters like `[Authorize]` will run so the dependency will always have to be met. From what I have read returning null is not ideal and I would have to change the Ninject configuration to do this anyway.

I was thinking that maybe the controller could get an instance of `ICrmServiceFactory` or something but that doesn't help me if the controllers end up having other dependencies which also rely on `CrmService` directly (and don't want to be passed a factory).

Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up implementing this as follows:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<CrmService>()
          .ToMethod(context =>
          {
            //return unauthenticated instance if user not logged in.
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return new CrmService();

            return GetConnection(HttpContext.Current);

          })
          .InRequestScope();
}

private static CrmService GetConnection(HttpContext ctx)
{
   //get stuff out of session and return service
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually set up a binding for IPrincipal:

```
kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

Never really had a problem with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then your controller has a dependency to `CrmService` and the `CrmService` requires some token stored in the session.

In that case you could inject a `CrmTokenProvider` to `CrmService` and add a property to that class which gets the value from the session whenever it is requested by the `CrmService`.

```
public class CrmService
{
    public CrmService(CrmTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork() 
    {
        ...
        this.tokenProvider.Token;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually have control of CrmService as it is a web reference. But I suppose I could inject a CrmServiceFactory or something and have that depend on CrmTokenProvider.